# Node repl module not found

Tags: node.js

I am trying to write a simple node script with some classes.
I first define a class

```
export default class Checkout() {
  constructor () {
    console.log('checkout')
  }
  check() {
    console.log('check')
  }
}
```

Then I am trying to use it

```
>node
>repl

check = new Checkout()
Uncaught ReferenceError: Checkout is not defined

require('Checkout')
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'Checkout'
```

How can I solve this? I am coming from Ruby where the console is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Where are you defining that class? It seems that you're trying to use it before you declare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in a file isn't included in any other scope outside of that file until you `require` or `import` the file. When requiring/importing, the name the object you exported from the file doesn't automatically get used, you still have to specify it.

However, you're currently mixing `require` (CommonJS module format) with `export default` (ECMAScript Module format). There is only very limited interoperability between these formats using dynamic `import()`, but it's not yet available in the Node REPL (open issue [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/33369)). If you need to test your Checkout class in the REPL, you'd need to just switch to using CommonJS:

```
module.exports = class Checkout() {
  constructor () {
    console.log('checkout')
  }
  check() {
    console.log('check')
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
> Checkout = require('checkout.js')
> check = new Checkout()
```

Comment: That won't work because that file is a module (uses `export` keyword) and can only be loaded via `import ... from`. However that is not currently supported in the REPL.

Comment: @TsvetanGanev thanks, I mistakenly thought interop between those was more forgiving.