# cannot dynamic import from data-uri in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, data-uri, dynamic-import

In the Node.js REPL I can dynamic import like this:

```sh
Welcome to Node.js v16.13.2.
Type ".help" for more information.
> let m = await import('data:text/javascript,export const x = 5;')
[Module: null prototype] { x: 5 }
> m.x
5
>
```

In pure Node.js, this also works:

```js
//main.js
export const m = await import('data:text/javascript,export const x = 5;');
```

```js
// index.js
import * as Main from './main.js';

console.log(Main.m.x);
```

and

```sh
$ node index.js
5
$
```

But this does not work in jest:

```js
//main.test.js
import * as Main from './main.js';

test('it loads', () => {
  expect(Main.m.x).toEqual(5);
});
```

Get error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'data:text/javascript,export const x = 5;' from 'main.js'
```

What's going on here?

My `package.json` (relevant parts):

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "27.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Here's an example:
    `let { date } = await import('quasar') // module under node_modules, or your own one, etc.
    date.getWeekOfYear(new Date())`

Related issues:
[Error: Cannot find module with dynamic import #6680](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6680)

[Node repl module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62678859/node-repl-module-not-found)

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev - [Node repl module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62678859/node-repl-module-not-found) is the **opposite** problem. :-) Here, the OP's code works in the REPL, and not when in a module.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks for your attention. I just accidentally copied wrong link. I'll edit ASAP.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How does it work for you? Note that I'm trying to use data-uri as the url. In real life this will be dynamic javascript-code.

Comment: @joegomain - I took the `export const m = await import('data:text/javascript,export const x = 5;');` code above, pasted it into `main.js`, created another file (`index.js`) that did `import { m } from "./main.js"; console.log(m.x);` and ran `node index.js`. It output `5`. (This was before the question mentioned jest. As I understand it, jest is still struggling a bit with ESM, but I don't know the details.)